# Have I Structure Map with Entity Framework constructed correctly with Context management in a wcf project

Tags: c#, entity-framework, wcf, structuremap, dbcontext

I have read other posts on this, and loads on net, but I am still unsure If what I have is fully correct..

I have use a servicehostfactory to initialise StructureMap in the appropriate service.. (based on [this](http://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2008/07/30/integrating-structuremap-with-wcf/))
Snippet below..

```
 public class StructureMapServiceHostFactory : ServiceHostFactory
    {
        public StructureMapServiceHostFactory()
        {
            Bootstrapper.ConfigureDependencies();
        }

        protected override ServiceHost CreateServiceHost(Type serviceType, Uri[] baseAddresses)
        {
            return new StructureMapServiceHost(serviceType, baseAddresses);
        }
    }
```

and the bootstrapping..

```
public static IContainer ConfigureDependencies()
        {
            if (AlreadyRegistered)
            {
                return ObjectFactory.Container;
            }

            lock (_lockThis)
            {
                if (AlreadyRegistered)
                {
                    return ObjectFactory.Container;
                }

                BootstrapStructureMap();
                AlreadyRegistered = true;
            }

            return ObjectFactory.Container;
        }

public static void BootstrapStructureMap()
        {
            ObjectFactory.Initialize(x =>
            {
                x.AddRegistry<InfrastructureRegistry>();
            });
        }

 public class InfrastructureRegistry : Registry
    {
        public InfrastructureRegistry()
        {
            For<Entities>().HybridHttpOrThreadLocalScoped().Use(c => new Entities());
```

...

The registering of my Entity Framework context is HybridHttpOrThreadLocalScoped. In the Application_EndRequest I am releasing http scoped objects which should be just the db context, as this I want per service request.

```
protected void Application_EndRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
Bootstrapper.ReleaseAndDisposeAllHttpScopedObjects();
        }

    public static void ReleaseAndDisposeAllHttpScopedObjects()
    {
        ObjectFactory.ReleaseAndDisposeAllHttpScopedObjects();
    }
```

Is this the correct approach or am I missing something? This way I should not need a using statement around my context, as it should be scoped to that request, and the next request gets another one.

Main reason is that from time to time, when I access a sub object on an entity, the object is null, whereas it should nto be and I am trying to eliminate the fact that it might be a shared context..

I tried to write out the context on Application_EndRequest

```
var instance = StructureMap.ObjectFactory.GetInstance<AXA_Entities.Entities>(); - write to file then
```

and the hashCode was unique, but Calling GetInstance will get me a new instance each time I would imagine?

I think I am close on this, but an explanation of something I am possibly missing is appreciated.

Ideally I want my scope to be like this.

```
For<Entities>().HttpContextScoped().Use(c => new Entities());
```

but I get the following method as a result.

```
"StructureMap Exception Code:  309\nYou cannot use the HttpContextLifecycle outside of a web request. Try the HybridLifecycle instead."
```

Comment: another of my questions that no one wants to answer. :S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[unitofwork-in-wcf-using-structuremap](http://andreasohlund.net/2009/04/27/unitofwork-in-wcf-using-structuremap/) answered what I should do.. there is other links inside so read carefully. I dont use the uow interface but the custom lifecycle is what I used in the end..

on version 2.6.4 of structuremap - latest version has changed some of the interfaces so havent upgraded yet.

```
For<Entities>().LifecycleIs(new WcfInstanceContextLifecycle()).Use(c
=> new Entities());
```